# How to use Taurus to run a jmeter script which has a properties file dependency and generate the log file

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I want to try out the Taurus framework to run my existing jmeter scripts. I usually run my scripts from the CLI like this:

```
jmeter -n -p .\config.properties -t .\HTTPS-REST\Done\load-scenario.jmx -l .\HTTPS-REST\TestResults\load-scenario-log.jtl
```

With the above command, I am loading a properties file which is necessary to populate some constant values in the jmeter script and I am logging all requests in a .jtl file as the test runs.

How can I achieve the same result with Taurus ?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to .properties file there are several ways to handle it:

1. In your [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory) there is a Taurus' special folder where it keeps downloaded tools called `.bzt` so you can rename your `config.properties` file to `~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/x.x.x./bin/user.properties` file and it will be picked up on next execution
2. If you switch to YAML test plan definition [to run existing .jmx script](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File) you will be able to convert .properties to YAML format like:

   ```
   modules:
     jmeter:
       properties:
         property1: value1
         property2: value2
         #etc.
   ```

   and then specify it via [included-configs](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/#Included-Configs) section
3. Individual properties or location of the `included-configs` or both can be set/overriden via `-o` command-line argument like:

   ```
   bzt -o modules.jmeter.properties.property1=value1 -o modules.jmeter.properties.property2=value2 test.jmx
   ```

Results file is available in the [artifacts directory](https://gettaurus.org/docs/CommandLine/#Artifacts), it is called `kpi.jtl`

More information:

- [Taurus - Command Line Tool](https://gettaurus.org/docs/CommandLine/#Artifacts)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Comment: I tried option 1 first, but the CLI log info just remains hung at a "INFO: Preparing..." and nothing is happening. I can't even use CTRL+C to close the execution - I have to close the  command prompt window. The bzt.log file which is created in my custom project root, show these last lines:
[2021-10-22 12:49:27,704 DEBUG JMX] Saving JMX to: C:\Users\xxxx\....\xxxxx\modified_scriptName-2.jmx
[2021-10-22 12:49:27,706 DEBUG root] Executing shell: ['C:\\Users\\xxxx\\.bzt\\jmeter-taurus\\5.2.1\\bin\\PluginsManagerCMD.bat', 'install-for-jmx', 'C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\...\\modified_scriptName-2.jmx'] at .

Answer (score 0):

The following link [Adding-JMeter-Properties](https://gettaurus.org/kb/Basic1/#Adding-JMeter-Properties) shows how add properties while executing the script using Taurus.

The JTL file will be available for download after the execution is done.

Comment: Ok, properties are added in yaml files. So if I want to use Taurus, I have to change my scripts' execution logic. How do I reference this yaml file in the CLI command?

Comment: No. Nothing to change on the JMeter script. Execute the script using bzt. See this link: https://gettaurus.org/

Comment: Blazemeter offers a free course on Taurus. See Blazemeter University (https://www.blazemeter.com/university/) for more information.